# getting a socket hang up error when trying to access my flask app in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask

Dockerfile

```
from ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip

COPY . /app

RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app/app.py"]
```

run commands

```
docker build -t flaskapp .
docker run -it -d p 5000:5000 flaskapp
```

if i sent a request to `localhost:5000` via Postman, i would get a `Error: Socket hang up` error

Anyone know why this is an issue?

Comment: Remove the `-d` flag from `docker run` to see the container logs in the terminal, which may reveal the problem (edit your question to append that log if not).

Comment: when using curl, i get a `Recv failure: connection reset by peer`

Comment: @v25 there are no errors. the flask app runs as it would locally

Answer (score 10):

the exposed host in my flask app was `127.0.0.1` in which i had to switch to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: This answer actually worked for me. I set my app's IP to `0.0.0.0` and I could finally access my container's address. Thanks for the help. I do find it weird that this fixed my issue though.

Comment: CMIIW: "host" means "accept connections addressed to this IP". 127.0.0.1 can only send to 127.0.0.1 - it's a special case. You need to accept requests addressed to your container's IP address (from the Docker bridge network), which is something like `172.17.0.2`. `0.0.0.0` means "accept anything I can (including `127.0.0.1` and `<my local network IP address>`)".

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and resolved it like via these two methods.
Try making either of these changes in your code:

**1.** Add hostname - Add any IP host (127.0.0.1 or whatever you like) in your flask code itself like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True,port='9999')
```

**2.** Add `WORKDIR` in your Dockerfile - Not mandatory but a try.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` will not work. That's only for self-communication - you need to be able to accept requests from the Docker daemon which is forwarding requests from your local machine. CMIIW 